Где и как хранить ресурсы в игре?
Я хочу создать rpg игру в юнити. В игре будет много ресурсов, например: уголь, железо, алмаз и т.д. У каждого из этих ресурсов будет название, описание, цена(которая зависит от редкости), редкость(обычная, хорошая, лучшая). Так вот, где лучше и как хранить такие ресурсы? Хорошим ли будет решения хранит это через ScriptableObject или есть другие способы?

Да, во время, игры там, после игры в PlayerPrefs сериализоаать можно.

ScriptableObject ничего не хранит. В редакторе данные в UnityEngine.Object сериализуются автоматически, а в билде только дисериализуются, но для этого можно использовать любой тип. И если ты не понял ни слова... читай интернет, инфы воз и не маленький товарняк.
